# How to get product ordered quantity column in sales grid in Magento2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, order-grid

How to get product **Ordered Quantity Column** in the sales grid in `Magento 2.2.6` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

you can get that value from `sales_order` `total_item_count` column. For that in your listing you need to use the renderer, and in that renderer class, load the order object and return the getTotalItemCount(), it will appear in your order listing. Hope that will help you.